# Alternate view to normal view in attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, table, string, values

I have somehow accidentally changed how my attribute table looks and I dont know how to get it to go back to the original state has anyone any idea how to change?

Comment: In the attribute table, at the bottom right, you will find two icons, press them to change the display mode